# Performance considerations for Thread.sleep() and schedulerExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, scheduledexecutorservice

I am trying to write a daemon thread for polling which will poll every "3" seconds. I've seen 3 approaches. I am not sure which one to go for ? I want to know the performance considerations. Which one could be consistant and will take smaller memory chunk ?

> Approach 1 :  Using the TimerTask  ( Not planning to use this )

```
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, firstTime, period)
```

> Approach 2 : Using ScheduledExecutorService
>
> Approach 3 : Using Thread.sleep() ....

If I boil down to code its something like this :

> Approach #2

```
public class Test {

    static TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
              // Do polling & Other business logic
            System.out.println("=="+new Date());
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
                .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(timerTask, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}
```

For the

> Approach #3

```
public class Test {

    static Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                // Do polling & Other business logic
                    System.out.println("**"+new Date());
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

}
```

According to my understanding threadpools are kind of heavy objects compared to normal threads. 
I want to know what are the pros and cons of using either of these approaches ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
JE

Comment: How many threads will be created?

Comment: @ErdinçTaşkın This daemon thread will be single that will poll and do something and sleep, again wakeup do something and sleep for fixed duration.

Comment: Only 1 thread at 3 seconds criteria does not matter about performance. I think you need to care other criteria.

Comment: It could be 3 or 30 or 300 seconds. It depends on the customer. We are giving that as a configurable parameter. Mostly its going to be 30 seconds. I am also concerned about heap space which w'd be occupied by each approach.

Comment: If you have too small/slow hardware or running too many instance of  applications you may need to care about it otherwise forget it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep pushing the msg at regular interval may cause overflow at the endpoint if for some reason endpoint become slow Hence I think you should consider throttling of pushing request as well instead of blindly pushing the requests at regular interval. Based on all such requirements I think you can opt for ExecutorService, Instead of TimerTask or low level thread approach.
Example of ExecutorService http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html